# Google Maps API3 - Making Google Markers Clickable, Polylines are already clickable (turn on and off via radiobox)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, sidebar

I am learning Google Maps API3 from your examples.  They are very helpful by the way.  I have one question.  In your example, http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GenericMapBrowser.asp?filename=flights090414.xml how would I make the Markers from IRS turn off along with the polyline?  But I would like to maintain the capability to have the markers clickable with data from the xml file that you have created.  I know it's somewhere in the following snippet of code.   Thank you so much for your help.

```
// A function to create the marker and set up the event window function 

function createMarker(latlng,name,html,icon) {
var contentString = html;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    icon: getMarkerImage(icon),
    shadow: iconShadow,
    map: map,
    title: name,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
    });
/*
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
*/
bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, contentString);
// save the info we need to use later for the side_bar
gmarkers.push(marker);
// add a line to the side_bar html
side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + 

')">' + name + '<\/a><br>';
 }

// This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info     

window
function myclick(i) {
google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}


  function togglePoly(poly_num) {
    if (document.getElementById('poly'+poly_num)) {
       if (document.getElementById('poly'+poly_num).checked) {
          gpolys[poly_num].setMap(map);
       } else {
          gpolys[poly_num].setMap(null);
       }
    }
  } 


  function createClickablePolyline(poly, html, label, point, length) {
    gpolys.push(poly);
    var poly_num = gpolys.length - 1;
    if (!html) {html = "";}
    else { html += "<br>";}
length = length * 0.000621371192; // convert meters to miles
    html += "length="+length.toFixed(2)+" miles";
    // html += poly.getLength().toFixed(2)+" m; 

 "+(poly.getLength()*3.2808399).toFixed(2)+" ft; ";
    // html += (poly.getLength()*0.000621371192).toFixed(2)+" miles";
    var contentString = html;
    google.maps.event.addListener(poly,'click', function(event) {
      infowindow.setContent(contentString);
      if (event) {
         point = event.latLng;
      }
      infowindow.setPosition(point);
      infowindow.open(map);
      // map.openInfoWindowHtml(point,html); 
    }); 
    if (!label) {
      label = "polyline #"+poly_num;
    }
    label = "<a 



  href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gpolys["+poly_num+"],\"
  click  \");'>"+label+"</a>";
    // add a line to the sidebar html
    side_bar_html += '<input type="checkbox" id="poly'+poly_num+'" 

  checked="checked" onclick="togglePoly('+poly_num+');">' + label + '<br 

  />';

  }
```

Comment: you can [**remove a marker**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#remove) or [**hide it**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove).

Comment: Thank you.  But how do I this with the code I listed above?   I would like to use this with a check mark like in the example.  Would you be able to show me?  I am a novice with this.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a loop over `gmarkers` removing/adding listeners. A few options would be `google.maps.event.removeListener(listenerHandle);` and `google.maps.event.clearListeners(objectListened, 'event');`